# Google Auth consent screen Unverified

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-developers-console

I already verified my Auth consent screen in Google console but it still showing me unverified when i try to login with google. Please See attached Screenshot for reference.

[image: Already Verified]

[image: Showing Unverified When i try to login]

I want solution or why it showing Unverified even i already verified it.